# Why use a superclass's __init__ to change it into a subclass?

Tags: python, design-patterns, subclass, superclass, monkeypatching

I'm working on replicating the [SHAP package](https://github.com/slundberg/shap) algorithm - an explainability algorithm for machine learning. I've been reading through the author's code, and I've come across a pattern I've never seen before.

The author has created a superclass called `Explainer`, which is a common interface for all the different model specific implementations of the algorithm. The `Explainer`'s `__init__` method accepts a string for the algorithm type and switches itself to the corresponding subclass if called directly. It does this using multiple versions of the following pattern:

```
if algorithm == "exact":
    self.__class__ = explainers.Exact
    explainers.Exact.__init__(self, self.model, self.masker, link=self.link, feature_names=self.feature_names, linearize_link=linearize_link, **kwargs)
```

I understand that this code sets the superclass to one of its subclasses and initialises the subclass by passing itself to `__init__`. But why would you do this?

Comment: I *wouldn't* do this. I would have defined an appropriate factory function (which could be a `Explainer` class method) that creates an instance of the appropriate type in the first place.

Comment: It seems odd to me too. The only thing I can think is that the author doesn't want `Explainer` to be instantiated as its own object at any time. Perhaps because it would be useless without the subclass implementation?

Comment: Maybe they should be doing this in the `__new__` method, not `__init__`

Comment: Not to mention this hack actually doesn't "switches itself to the corresponding subclass", rather it is simply calling the subclasses `__init__` method and hence misses out on any extra methods / attributes of the subclass. Which basically means you might as well not have that subclass as the only useful thing in it is the `__init__` method, it could have simply been an attribute on the `Explainer` class.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Wouldn't switching the `__class__` type give it access to the all the methods? And wouldn't using `__init__` assign all of the subclass's attributes?

Comment: `__new__` has its own issues when you try to turn it into a factory function for its own subclasses. It's cleaner, IMO, to use a separate function that's outside the normal path of instance creation.

Comment: Calling the `__init__` of some other class does not add its method / attribute on the current class. If something like that happened things like `super().__init__()` etc. wouldn't be that useful.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat instance attributes belong to instances, not classes. Calling the other class' `__init__` does add the instance attributes, assuming that the code for that `__init__` says normal things like `self.attribute = value`; such code **does not actually care** about the type of `self` (except insofar as that triggers custom `__setattr__` logic or is blocked on built-in types). Changing the `__class__` attribute, meanwhile, **does** give access to class attributes and methods (which are not "added" to the instance in any event).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat But `self.__class__` does provide for proper inheritance. (Inheritance in Python is really just a matter of looking for inherited methods in the right place, according to the MRO of `self.__class__`.) Calling the `__init__` method explicitly means any calls to `super().__init__` inside are dispatched correctly. The bigger issue is what state an instance that's been initialized *twice* is in.

Comment: Ah, I did miss the `self.__class__ = explainers.Exact` part @KarlKnechtel yes.

Comment: I edited my answer to give full details showing how that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a non-standard and awkward way of implementing the Abstract Factory design pattern. The idea is that, although the base class contains state and functionality that are useful for implementing derived classes, it should not be instantiated directly. The full code contains logic that checks whether the base class `__init__` is being called "directly" or via `super`; in the former case, it checks a parameter and chooses an appropriate derived class. (That derived class, of course, will end up calling back to this `__init__`, but this time `super` is used, so there is no unbounded recursion.)

To clarify, although this is not standard, it does work:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, *, value=None, kind=None):
        if self.__class__ is Base:
            if kind == 'derived':
                self.__class__ = Derived
                Derived.__init__(self, value)
            else:
                raise ValueError("invalid 'kind'; cannot create Base instances explicitly")

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = value
    def method(self):
        return 'derived method not defined in base'
```

Testing it:

```
>>> Base()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in __init__
ValueError: invalid 'kind'; cannot create Base instances explicitly
>>> Base(value=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in __init__
ValueError: invalid 'kind'; cannot create Base instances explicitly
>>> Base(value=1, kind='derived')
<__main__.Derived object at 0x7f94fe025790>
>>> Base(value=1, kind='derived').method()
'derived method not defined in base'
>>> Base(value=1, kind='derived').value
1
>>> Derived(2)
<__main__.Derived object at 0x7f94fcc2aa00>
>>> Derived(2).method()
'derived method not defined in base'
>>> Derived(2).value
2
```

Setting the `__class__` attribute allows the factory-created `Derived` instance to access the derived `method`, and calling `__init__` causes it to have a per-instance `value` attribute. In fact, we could do those steps in either order, because the Derived `__init__` is invoked explicitly rather than via method lookup. Alternatively, it would work (although it would look strange) to call `self.__init__(value)`, but only *after* changing the `__class__`.

---

A more Pythonic way to implement this is to use the standard library `abc` functionality to mark the base class as "abstract", and use a named method as a factory. For example, decorating the base class `__init__` with `@abstractmethod` will prevent it from being instantiated directly, while forcing derived classes to implement `__init__`. When they do, they will call `super().__init__`, which will work without error. For the factory, we can use a method decorated with `@staticmethod` in the base class (or just an ordinary function; but using `@staticmethod` effectively "namespaces" the factory). It can, for example, use a string name to choose a derived class, and instantiate it.

A minimal example:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Base(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    @staticmethod
    def create(kind):
        # TODO: add more derived classes to the mapping
        return {'derived': Derived}[kind]()

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

# TODO: implement additional derived classes
```

Testing it:

```
>>> Base()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Base with abstract methods __init__
>>> Derived()
<__main__.Derived object at 0x7f94fe025310>
>>> Base.create('derived')
<__main__.Derived object at 0x7f94fe025910>
```

Comment: Does that mean it's likely the author was unaware of the `abc` standard library when they wrote the code? Leading them to replicate the functionality in their own way?

Comment: Possibly unaware; possibly just didn't think of it; possibly has some other ideological objection. Another explanation that could apply in other situations is "the code has been in development since before the standard library feature existed"; however, that doesn't apply here - ABCs were introduced in 3.0, and the repository only dates back to 2016.